# Why is my IIS website showing my Xfinity gateway login page?

Tags: iis, windows-10, web-hosting

I am trying to host a website on my machine via IIS with Windows 10 Pro. My machine is currently connected to my router which is directly connected to my Xfinity gateway. On my host machine I get everything set even with my bindings. When I test the site as it should it works properly on the host machine. When I test on my other machine that is directly connected to the Xfinity gateway it just takes me to the Xfinity gateway login page?

Comment: How did you connect the site? Domain name or machine IP? If you used domain for connection, did you set public DNS or machine local DNS.

Comment: You might get some hints from https://blog.lextudio.com/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.  It would help if you added the requested details from the other comments before you re-ask there.

Comment: @BruceZhang I use noip to allow me to connect to it outside gateway network.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller and yes this is a programing questions. Last I checked TCP/IP what partly programming

Comment: If this is a programming question, then please [edit] your question to include the code.  It sounds like it is more of a website configuration question to me.  If it is a network configuration question, you would ask it at [sf], although this sounds like home networking which is off-topic there.